# Click Multiple Buttons with RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, registerstartupscript

I have an ASP content page with three grids in one UpdatePanel, and a separate refresh button associated with each grid.  When the page loads, the grids are empty.  If I then click each refresh button, one at a time, and wait between each step, all three grids will populate correctly.

In my first version of this page, I would pre-populate the grids before rendering the initial page load.  However, each grid is slow to refresh, and I want to improve the user experience - the initial load took about 30 seconds. I thought I could AJAXify the page so that it first loads quickly (with empty grids), then all three refreshes are fired independently from Javascript, and each grid is filled as soon as its respective refresh call returns, in whatever order they happen to be ready.  That way the user does not have to wait for all three to complete before at least some data is available.

If I want to automate the initial fill of only one grid, I can easily use this technique:

```
if (!IsPostBack)            
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshGridA", "document.getElementById('" + btnRefreshGridA.ClientID + "').click();", true);
```

I have used this many times when there is only one long-running report I want to fire, and it works just fine here. But this is a scenario I haven't ever considered before - if I try to do this for more than one grid:

```
if (!IsPostBack)            
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshGridA", "document.getElementById('" + btnRefreshGridA.ClientID + "').click();", true);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshGridB", "document.getElementById('" + btnRefreshGridB.ClientID + "').click();", true);
}
```

... then the only refresh that completes is the final one.  I guess I shouldn't be surprised, because if I replicate this manually, and click one refresh button immediately after another, I get the same result - the first AJAX call appears to be abandoned. Is that what's happening?

Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  What is the correct approach for coordinating multiple, independent, simultaneous AJAX calls?  I suspect I shouldn't be using the buttons at all, but I've had a lot of success with this approach when only one button is involved.  I've tried combining the clicks into a single script, and I've tried wrapping each grid/button pair in its own UpdatePanel, but I get the same result with both of those variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1108522.aspx), I found a javascript event queue that helps me do what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.add_load(ApplicationLoadHandler)

     function ApplicationLoadHandler(sender, args) {
         var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
             prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
             prm.add_endRequest(CompleteRequest);
         }
     }

     var myQueue = new Array();

     function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
         var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {// if it's working on another request, cache the current item that cause the request
             args.set_cancel(true);
             Array.add(myQueue, args.get_postBackElement());
         }
     }

     function CompleteRequest(sender, args) {
         if (myQueue.length > 0) {// fire corresponding event again of the item cached
             $get(myQueue[0].id).click();
             Array.removeAt(myQueue, 0);
         }
     }

     if (typeof (Sys) !== "undefined") Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
</script>
```

This can also be rendered from codebehind like this:

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.Append("Sys.Application.add_load(ApplicationLoadHandler)\n");

script.Append("function ApplicationLoadHandler(sender, args) {\n");
script.Append("    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();\n");
script.Append("    if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {\n");
script.Append("        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);\n");
script.Append("        prm.add_endRequest(CompleteRequest);\n");
script.Append("    }\n");
script.Append("}\n");

script.Append("var myQueue = new Array();\n");

script.Append("function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {\n");
script.Append("    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();\n");
script.Append("    if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {\n");
script.Append("    args.set_cancel(true);\n");
script.Append("    Array.add(myQueue, args.get_postBackElement());\n");
script.Append("    }\n");
script.Append("}\n");

script.Append("function CompleteRequest(sender, args) {\n");
script.Append("    if (myQueue.length > 0) {\n");
script.Append("        $get(myQueue[0].id).click();\n");
script.Append("        Array.removeAt(myQueue, 0);\n");
script.Append("    }\n");
script.Append("}\n");

script.Append("if (typeof (Sys) !== \"undefined\") Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EventQueue", script.ToString(), true);
```

Regardless of the method of adding this queue script, I found that I needed to add a slight delay to the button clicks to get them to queue up:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshGridA", "setTimeout(\"document.getElementById('" + btnRefreshGridA.ClientID + "').click();\",100);", true);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshGridB", "setTimeout(\"document.getElementById('" + btnRefreshGridB.ClientID + "').click();\",100);", true);
```

Without the setTimeout, only the last button would complete its refresh, as before.

Fundamentally, the refresh calls are not actually multithreaded; they are executed serially.  However, I'm now satisfied with the user experience.